# LEFT JOIN on Inline Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Google hasn't helped me here nor has Microsoft online help yet.

I have Inline tables which are generated as a subquery. (See simplified code below, I have several more inline tables.)

Now, this is fine where I have data. However, there are cases where I need to return results when there isn't data. For example, Inline table 1 returns my number of active customers... If I specifiy a range where there are no active customers I get no results for the whole query.

This is due to my join (AND IL1.transaction_id = th.transaction_id)

How can I left join the inline table?

I tried LEFT JOIN IL1 on il1.transaction_id = th.transaction_id but it says the table doesn't exist.

```
select  SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
            IL1.Active as 'Number of Active Customers TY',
            COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY'

FROM        

(SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' from transaction_header  
where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate group by transaction_type)IL1, 
transaction_header th

INNER JOIN transaction_type tt ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type
WHERE 
th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate

AND         IL1.transaction_type = th.transaction_type

GROUP BY 
            tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: "BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate" seems wrong there.

Comment: Can you post the query you tried with the left join that didn't work please?

Comment: It works as is, for example, if my from date is 1st jan, my to date is 30th october and my active date is 5th april, i get number of customers active between 5th - april and 30th october, but my other results go from 1st jan - 30th october. However, if there have been no active cutomers it'll generate a null and my join will be a null so i get no results overall.. you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mix implicit and explicit joins, you may get inconsistent results. Also well frankly you should never use an implicit join.

See if this works for you:

```
SELECT  SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) AS 'Net Purchases  TY',  
            COALESCE(IL1.Active, 0) AS 'Number of Active Customers TY', 
            COUNT(th.transaction_id) AS 'Number of Transactions TY' 

FROM     transaction_header th      
INNER JOIN transaction_type tt 
    ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS 'Active' 
            FROM transaction_header   
            WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate 
            GROUP BY transaction_type)IL1
    ON  IL1.transaction_type = th.transaction_type 
WHERE  th.transaction_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
GROUP BY  tt.transaction_type_description, COALESCE(IL1.Active, 0)
```

Comment: This is interesting.. I had looked at CTE (as per the previous answer) but I forgot to mention one of the machines runs SQL 2000. COALESCE might be useful. I'll give this a shot too, many thanks for your input.

Comment: Right... usually (when there is data in all parameters) my query takes about 49 seconds to run. I changed the IL tables to LEFT joins and now my query has been running for over 10 minutes without returning data. I think theres a problem. I'll try and isolate the cause. Many thanks.

Comment: I'd say there is definitely a problem.

Comment: The Problem is that some of my inline tables may return no rows (be empty) in this case joining to an empty table seems to be what is making the query take forever. I thought that the left join would have fixed this but maybe i misunderstood how it works. Does this make sense? Do you have any suggestions about it? Many thanks

Comment: First I'd check to make sure that all the join fields are indexed and the transaction date inthe where clause. FKs are not indexed by default.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're running SQL Server 2005, I'm going to use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to clean this up a bit.

```
;with cteIL1 as (
    SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' 
        from transaction_header  
        where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate 
        group by transaction_type
)
select  SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
        ac.Active as 'Number of Active Customers TY',
        COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY'
    FROM transaction_header th
        INNER JOIN transaction_type tt 
            ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type
        LEFT JOIN cteIL1 IL1
            on th.transaction_type = IL1.transaction_type
    WHERE th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate
    GROUP BY tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active
```

**EDIT**: Non-CTE version for 2000 as mentioned in comments:

```
select  SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
        ac.Active as 'Number of Active Customers TY',
        COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY'
    FROM transaction_header th
        INNER JOIN transaction_type tt 
            ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT transaction_type, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' 
                       from transaction_header  
                       where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate 
                       group by transaction_type
                   ) IL1
            on th.transaction_type = IL1.transaction_type
    WHERE th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate
    GROUP BY tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active
```

Comment: I see... I did look into CTE but I should have mentioned (while the query i'm developing is on a SQL SERVER 2005 box) one of the machines it will be used on is running SQL 2000... However, I can incorporate the CTE into the SQL 2005 machines.. i'll give this a go. Thank you for your input

Comment: @Wes Price: For the 2000 box, simply move the SELECT from the CTE back inline again. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Fantastic... I think I may have misunderstood how a left join would improve my syntax. Some of my inline tables can be empty. If I try to join on the empty table it takes an exponential amount of time to do anything. Do you know how i'd rememdy this? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select  SUM(th.total_net_retail_central) as 'Net Purchases  TY', 
            IL1.Active as 'Number of Active Customers TY',
            COUNT(th.transaction_id) as 'Number of Transactions TY'
FROM        
(SELECT transaction_type, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as 'Active' 
         from transaction_header  
    where transaction_date BETWEEN @Active and @ToDate 
     group by transaction_type ) IL1
     right join
                transaction_header th
                 on IL1.transaction_type = th.transaction_type
INNER JOIN transaction_type tt 
            ON th.transaction_type = tt.transaction_type
WHERE 
th.transaction_date Between @FromDate AND @ToDate
GROUP BY 
            tt.transaction_type_description, IL1.Active
```

If I am reading this correctly I believe that you need a **RIGHT JOIN** between IL1 and TH

IL1
         right join
                    transaction_header th
                     on IL1.transaction_type = th.transaction_type

Comment: @HLGEM answer is more maintainable (since it seems easier to read and thus maintain to have the inner joins at the top and then the left join at the end as opposed to starting off with an RIGHT join --I was just trying to leave the statement alone as much as possible)